# AzureAD Custom Claims in token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm struggling with custom claims policy for one of applications. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to get AzureAD User property MailNickName in to uppercase and be included in JWT. At this point I really cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

This is custom policy which I'm expecting to do the job:

```
$policy1 = @('{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":{
        "Version":  1,
        "IncludeBasicClaimSet":  true,
        "ClaimsSchema":[
            {
                "Source":  "user",
                "ID":  "mailnickname"
            },   
            {
                "Source":"transformation",
                "ID":"testmailnickname",
                "TransformationId":"ChangeToUpper",
                "JwtClaimType":"mailnickname"
            }
        ],
        "ClaimsTransformations":[{
            "ID":"ChangeToUpper",
            "TransformationMethod":"ChangeCase",
            "InputClaims":[{
                "ClaimTypeReferenceId":"mailnickname",
                "TransformationClaimType":"inputClaim1"
            }], 
            "InputParameters":[{
                "ID":"toCase",
                "DataType":"string",
                "Value":"UPPER"
            }],
            "OutputClaims":[{
                "ClaimTypeReferenceId":"testmailnickname",
                "TransformationClaimType":"outputClaim"
            }]
        }]
    }
}')
```

However, when checking what's inside JWT, I basically get nothing. I was trying with other policies, for instance found example which suppose to add "sandbox" to MailNickName - it really works.

```
$policy2 = @('{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":{
        "Version":1,
        "IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema":[{
            "Source":"user",
            "ID":"mailnickname"
        },{
            "Source":"transformation",
            "ID":"DataJoin",
            "TransformationId":"JoinTheData",
            "JwtClaimType":"JoinedData"
        }],
        "ClaimsTransformations":[{
            "ID":"JoinTheData",
            "TransformationMethod":"Join",
            "InputClaims":[{
                "ClaimTypeReferenceId":"mailnickname",
                "TransformationClaimType":"string1"}], 
                "InputParameters": [{
                    "ID":"string2",
                    "Value":"sandbox"
                },{
                    "ID":"separator",
                    "Value":"."
                }],
                "OutputClaims":[{
                    "ClaimTypeReferenceId":"DataJoin",
                    "TransformationClaimType":"outputClaim"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }')
```

When having this policy created, we are assigning it to our App Registration.

```
$pol =  New-AzureADPolicy -Definition ($policy1) -DisplayName ("Policy_Test_1" + ([System.Guid]::NewGuid().guid)) -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault $false
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $SP.ObjectId -RefObjectId $pol.Id
```

Basing on [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#example-of-changecase) regarding this topic, everything seems to be fine, but still doesn't get uppercased MailNickName value inside the token. This means that I'm doing something wrong, but I really cannot see my mistake.

Comment: What's the use case that you are using JSON rather than XML?

Comment: Youve used AAD docs when referring to JSON. Youve refernced an AAD B2C article, which uses XML. Two different products, methods and docs. Is it AAD youre using, or AAD B2C?

Comment: @rbrayb Answering you both friends, I just simply messed up. We were trying to look for solution that much and focused on changing property case, that we didn't even noticed that this documentation is for different solution... We thought that those can be reused as well since keys naming in JSON and XML was basically the same. I've edited question, we are trying to assign AAD policy to App Registration to get value of this field inside JWT.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the referred documentation is for [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/), Microsoft CIAM. **For Azure AD the available [transformations methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-claims-mapping-policy-type#table-4-transformation-methods-and-expected-inputs-and-outputs) are Join and ExtractMailPrefix.**

Comment: Yes, you are right, we were trying to look for solution and thought that this is just different representation, since names were basically the same. I've edited my question giving example how we are using it. So as I understand it, there is basically no way of getting AAD user property to uppercase? And that because that we can use only Join or ExtractMailPrefix, is this right?

Comment: That's correct but new methods have been planned. Stay tuned!